# python setup.py fails on osx with ssl error

Tags: python, macos, ssl, setup.py

I am trying to upload a new python project from my mac to PyPI via:

`python setup.py sdist upload -r pypi`

When I try to upload a package, I get the following error on `OSX`:

```
Submitting dist/PyTreasuryDirect-0.1.0.tar.gz to https://pypi.python.org/pypi
error: <urlopen error [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:581)>
```

This question is slightly related to these two questions, [ssl with pip](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25981703/pip-install-fails-with-connection-error-ssl-certificate-verify-failed-certi) and [when importing the ssl library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27835619/ssl-certificate-verify-failed-error). However I need setup.py to work in my case, how can I get past this ssl error?

I also get the same error on Python 2.7.9 and Python 3.5 using OSX 10.10.2 (14C109)

Comment: MacOSX 10.9+ switched from OpenSSL to SecureTransport for the SSL module.   This is a major change in the way tools handle self-signed or unknown signed certificates.  (e.g. this impacts [curl][1] for example)  Is it possible you have an SSL proxy in the middle, and it does not like the self signed cert of the MitM proxy?  




  [1]: http://curl.haxx.se/mail/archive-2013-10/0036.html

Comment: @cgseller I think its a problem with how `setup.py` is handling ssl and I'm not sure how to fix it. I can get ssl to work on my mac via the other soltuion's but that invovles `pip` or the `openssl` package.

Comment: On OS X 10.10 with python 2.7.6 no such problem. You might be affected by [this issue](http://bugs.python.org/issue23052): "Python 2.7.9 enabled certificate validation by default for HTTP connections, see PEP476."

Comment: @baf make this an answer, I simply had to use the default python from /usr/bin/python and not the macports or anaconda or hombrew version.....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution for OS X 10.10 is to use its default Python version 2.7.6.

This problem is related to the fact that starting from Python version 2.7.9 certificate validation for stdlib http clients is enabled by default ([PEP 476](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0476/)). This issue is described in [Python bug tracker](http://bugs.python.org/issue23052).

Comment: That's not at all a solution. Various setup.py scripts simply don't run on Python 2.7, so what should they do?